# Python regular expression to match everything until the last occurrence of <br> before string with :

Tags: python, regex

How can I create regular expression to return data in a correct way? I think I should  somehow use lookahead, but I can't figure out the correct way.

My code:

```
import re

txt = "Person:Tester Test<br>Count:1<br>Testing:test<br>Additional Information:test1<br>test2<br>test3<br>Temp:123<br>"
x = re.findall("(.*?<br>)", txt)

for i in x:
 print("- " + i)
```

What  it returns now:

```
- Person:Tester Test<br>
- Count:1<br>
- Testing:test<br>
- Additional Information:test1<br>
- test2<br>
- test3<br>
- Temp:123<br>
```

What i would like to get as a result is:

```
- Person:Tester Test<br>
- Count:1<br>
- Testing:test<br>
- Additional Information:test1<br>test2<br>test3<br>
- Temp:123<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
.*?<br>(?=\w+:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/01UJnk/1).

*Details*:

- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `<br>` - a fixed string
- `(?=\w+:|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more letters/digits/underscores and then a colon immediately to the right of the current location, or end of string.

Comment: Thank you! (?=\D+:|$) seems to be working nice too.

Comment: @Scooby That depends on what kind of chars there should be before `:`. If either works, it is great.

Comment: I am struggling now with white spaces in the "name column". .*?<br>(?=\w+:|$) is now matching it like this: "Testing:test<br>Additional Information:test1<br>test2<br>test3<br>", but it should match "Testing:test<br>" and "Additional Information:test1<br>test2<br>test3<br>" separetly.

Comment: @Scooby Add the space to the `\w` pattern, `.*?<br>(?=[\w ]+:|$)` / `.*?<br>(?=[\w\s]+:|$)`